# Neo4J browser with Bolt protocol does not work on my server

Tags: neo4j

Neo4J browser with Bolt protocol does not work on my server.

Here is the error I get in the browser (Chrome):

```
VM608:35 WebSocket connection to 'ws://<server_name>:7687/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
WrappedWebSocket  @ VM608:35
l @ 8eea4b31.components.js:61
c @ 8eea4b31.components.js:61
value @ 8eea4b31.components.js:60
value @ 8eea4b31.components.js:61
value @ 8eea4b31.components.js:60
value @ 8eea4b31.components.js:60
testConnection  @ 248a7ab3.scripts.js:10
makeRequest @ 248a7ab3.scripts.js:11
AuthService.makeRequest @ 248a7ab3.scripts.js:5
AuthService.authenticate  @ 248a7ab3.scripts.js:5
(anonymous) @ 248a7ab3.scripts.js:9
$scope.authenticate @ 248a7ab3.scripts.js:5
(anonymous) @ 8eea4b31.components.js:13
callback  @ 8eea4b31.components.js:13
$eval @ 8eea4b31.components.js:11
$apply  @ 8eea4b31.components.js:11
(anonymous) @ 8eea4b31.components.js:13
dispatch  @ 8eea4b31.components.js:3
elemData.handle @ 8eea4b31.components.js:3
```

And here is the error in Neo4J logs on the server:

```
2017-05-23 16:43:11.130+0000 WARN  [io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception. Connection reset by peer
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
  at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
  at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
  at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:366)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:118)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to search for this error but didn't find a solution.

Following is the network part of Neo4J configuration:

```
#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.
#dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost

# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473

# Number of Neo4j worker threads.
#dbms.threads.worker_count=
```

I made Neo4J accessible from outside by telling it to listen on 0.0.0.0.
I used `telnet <server_name> 7687` to check the port was opened and it is.

If I disable Bolt it is working fine.

Does someone has an idea about what is going wrong?

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: The version is 3.1.0.